# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '.\DbConnect.php' (include_path='B:\xamp\php\pear')

Tags: php, pear

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '.\DbConnect.php'
>   (include_path='B:\xamp\php\pear') in
>   B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php on line 12

```
<?php
include'B:\xamp\php\pear';
class DbOperations{
private $con;
function __construct(){
     require_once dirname(_FILE_).'/DbConnect.php'; -->Error
     $db = new DbConnect();
     $this->con = $db->connect();
 }
 /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE*/
/*********************STUDENT TABLE******************************/
function createstudent($username,$password,$email){
    $password = md5($pass);
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `tbl_student` (`id`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `CourseName`, `Semester`, `RegDate`, `updationDate`) VALUES (NULL, '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', current_timestamp(), NULL);");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);
    /*$stmt->bind_param(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bind_param(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bind_param(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);*/
    if($stmt->excute()){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

I have specified the right path for the pear , but still, the same error is popping up not sure what's wrong.

This is DbConnect.php

```
<?php 
//include('B:\xamp\php\pear');
class DbConnect{
    private $con;
    function __construct(){
    }
    function connect(){
        include_once dirname(_FILE_).'/Constants.php';
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect with Database".mysqli_connect_err();
        }
        return $this->con;
    }
}
?>
```

Error messages

> Warning: include(B:\xamp\php\pear): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\admin\includes\DbOperation.php on
>   line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'B:\xamp\php\pear' for inclusion
>   (include_path='B:\xamp\php\pear') in
>   B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\admin\includes\DbOperation.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(B:\xamp\php\pear): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'B:\xamp\php\pear' for inclusion
>   (include_path='B:\xamp\php\pear') in
>   B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php on line 3
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant *FILE* - assumed '*FILE*' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php on line 12
>
> Warning: require_once(.\DbConnect.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php
>   on line 12
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '.\DbConnect.php'
>   (include_path='B:\xamp\php\pear') in
>   B:\xamp\htdocs\Library\includes\DbOperations.php on line 12

Comment: `'?'` this is a string with literal `?` instead of parameter.

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: What exactly is the reason for this error?

Comment: echo out this `dirname(_FILE_).'/DbConnect.php';` and verify if the path to the file is correct